# Probabilty that quicksort partition creates an imbalanced partition

Tags: algorithms, algorithm-analysis, probability-theory, quicksort

I have come across this question:

> Let 0<α<.5 be some constant (independent of the input array length n). Recall the Partition subroutine employed by the QuickSort algorithm, as explained in lecture. What is the probability that, with a randomly chosen pivot element, the Partition subroutine produces a split in which the size of the smaller of the two subarrays is ≥α times the size of the original array?

The answer is 1-2*α.

Can anyone explain me how has this answer come?

Comment: What have you tried and where did you get stuck? Hint: try to figure out the probability that the pivot has rank $k$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If $\alpha=0.5$, then $1-2 * 0.5 = 0$, which says that the smaller subarray cannot have length greater than half the original, since then it would be the larger subarray.

If $\alpha=0$, then $1-2 * 0 = 1$, so the size of any subarray must be greater than or equal to zero.

The pivot is randomly chosen, so uniformly distributed between $0$ and $1$. The probability that a particular subarray has size $\geq a = 1-a$. Probability that that particular subarray is also less than half the size of the original $= 0.5-\alpha$. If you're talking about not a particular subarray but whichever one is the smallest, then double it, meaning it has probability $1.0$ of being between $0$ and $0.5$ the length of the original. That is $p=1-2\alpha$.

That explanation makes intuitive sense to me. Basically the answer just says the size of the smaller subarray is uniformly distributed between $0$ and $0.5$ the size of the original.

Answer (score 3):

The other answers didn't quite click with me so here's another take:

If at least one of the 2 subarrays must be  [image: formula] you can deduce that the pivot must also be in position [image: formula]. This is obvious by contradiction. If the pivot is [image: formula] then there is a subarray smaller than [image: formula]. By the same reasoning the pivot must also be [image: formula]. Any larger value for the pivot will yield a smaller subarray than [image: formula] on the "right hand side".

This means that [image: formula], as shown by the diagram below:

[image]

What we want to calculate then is the probability of that event (call it A) i.e [image: formula].

The way we calculate the probability of an event is to sum of the probability of the constituent outcomes i.e. that the pivot lands at [image: formula].

That sum is expressed as:

[image]

Which easily simplifies to:

[image]

With some cancellation we get:

[image]

Comment: Nice and illustrative. Just in case, we have LaTeX support https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: @Evil oh cool. I'll edit when I get a chance.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to think about this, which maybe helpful is, to pick a concrete value of $\alpha$ and the size of the original array, $n$.  Lets say that $\alpha = 0.2$ and $n = 100$. Then, $\alpha n = 20$. Lets also denote the size of the smaller subarray by $|S|$.

If the pivot chosen is at index $21$, then the size of the smaller subarray, $|S|$ is $20$ (remember that the pivot is excluded in the particular partition algorithm under discussion). This satisfies the condition that $|S| \ge \alpha n$.

Now, lets look at $1 - \alpha = 0.8$. Then $(1-\alpha)n = 80$ for our choice of $n$. Now, the pivot needs to be at index $80$ or less. Say, the pivot is at index 80. The size of $|S| = 100 - 81 + 1 = 20$ and satisfies the condition that $|S| \ge \alpha n$. If the pivot, is say, at index 81, then $|S| = 100 - 82 + 1 = 19$ and this violates the minimum size requirement on $|S|$.

Hence, we see that the pivot must be sandwiched between $\alpha n$ and $(1-\alpha)n$. That is, $$\alpha n \lt p \le (1-\alpha)n$$
Since pivots are chosen uniformly at random, the required probability is the size of the interval into which the pivot must fall divided by the number of elements in the original array. That is
$$Pr = \frac{(1-\alpha)n - \alpha n}{n} = 1 - 2\alpha$$